# Include existing PHP files and functions into Slim results in empty variables being passed back

Tags: php, json, rest, slim

I am beginning to use Slim for REST/Json web services. Now, after initial tests, I realize that I would need to include PHP code which I use for my "normal" web application, in order to calculate the right values to be returned. [*That is, instead of returning national statistics, I calculate per capita data or indexed values or aggregations.*]

Now, my PHP code in the included file (see below, B) calls a function from another file (C). This works fine. But the value generated in that function is not being brought back to the first file (B).

- A: Code Slim level.... include (xx.php, yy.php)
- B: xx.php: call_to_function_from_yy()
- C: yy.php: generate result; global $results (with $results having indeed values)
- B: $results is empty

Any hints why that would be and what I can do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your yy.php has something like this:

```
function returnResults($parameter) {
 /*
  * your pretty code here
  */
 return $results;
}
```

And your xx.php file does something like this:

```
require_once $path_to_your_file . '/yy.php';
 /*
  * your pretty code here
  */

$myResults = returnResults($myParameter);

 /*
  * your pretty code here
  */
```

In this way you get the result from yy.php in xx.php, I can improve this answer if you could who a lil' snippet of yy.php and xx.php.

Comment: Thanks for that. But not all of the included files do have functions. Some are just "normal" code which has been "outsourced" in order to thin a bit the principal file. I guess this is where the problem lies now...

Comment: Coming back to this, yes, it's indeed like that. In xx.php I have `db_query("SELECT * FROM countries")` and in yy.php I have `function db_query($query) { global $result; $result = pg_query($query); }`. I don't have a `return $result` as it's anyway global. It seems however that I need to call the function now (in contrast to the working non-Slim version before) with `$result = db_query('...')` and `return $result`. Then it seems to work.